# Exception from Meteor._atFlush: undefined

Tags: meteor

I'm discovering Meteor and all is working quite well.

I have now an error in the client console:
Exception from Meteor._atFlush: undefined

The application is working well... I don't manage to find when this error appeared and why...

Do you have an idea of the origin of such an error?

EDIT: these lines make this bug appear:

```
Template.description.rendered = function() {
CKEDITOR.inlineAll();
}
```

I don't know enough how meteor is working inside to understand why this bug appears. If someone can help me...

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I'm continuing to developp this app and this error is still here. If you need more informations to help me, ask please. I don't like having such an error on the console.

Comment: Can you paste all of your javascript code and the html as well, as concise as possible to reproduce the error? That would help in figuring out what's going on. Also, you might find these screencasts helpful if you'd like to learn more about what's going on under the hood: http://www.eventedmind.com